# Preferences in Evernote API

Tags: evernote

[The Evernote API docs list a number of constants relating to "preferences,"](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Limits.html#Const_EDAM_MAX_PREFERENCES) a key/value store containing things like shortcuts.  However, there do not appear to be any actual methods in the API for accessing or otherwise working with these preferences.  Have I overlooked something in the docs, is the full support un(der)documented, or are the constants just useless at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences are used by our first party apps, who have access to the latest versions of our thrift interfaces and docs. The version of our docs online doesn't have the latest methods/documentation.